# How do you use ogrinfo with a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, ogr

How do you use `ogrinfo` with a SQL Server database?

I've tracked down documentation on it at [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) and it mentions ...

> datasource_name:
>   The data source to open. May be a filename, directory or other virtual name. See the OGR Vector Formats list for supported datasources.

and I'd hope this has an answer, but the link [OGR Vector Formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) gives a 404 error

Comment: New link is http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html. Driver manual page is at http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for the corrected link, but any chance of an actual example?  The two on the ogrinfo page refer to wrk and I can't even find that in the list

Comment: There is an ogrinfo example at the bottom of http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html, have you tried it?

Comment: Didn't find that page ... success ... many thanks.  PS. post an answer so I can vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to use with different [GDAL vector drivers](http://gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) varies as well as how and where the syntax is documented in the corresponding driver pages. The [SQL Server driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html) manual page has section "Connecting to a database" with basic instruction

> To connect to a MSSQL datasource, use a connection string specifying
>   the database name, with additional parameters as necessary. The
>   connection strings must be prefixed with 'MSSQL:'.
>
> ```
> MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=dbname;trusted_connection=yes
> ```

The same manual page gives also advice for advanced connection options and an example about how to use ogrinfo with SQL Server

```
ogrinfo -al "MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=geodb;tables=rivers;trusted_connection=yes"
```